# Chrome CSS failing

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Hi I am trying to change the css for a `select` element, and it works fine in firefox but it doesnt work in google chrome. When I tried to use the Chrome Developer tool, I see that under `Styles/Matched CSS Rules` the elements height is successfully changed to `30px` but when I go to `Computed Style` the `height` shows up as `18px` but when I click the arrow to get more information it shows that the height should be `30px`

```
#new-job select - 30px
```

I am new with html/css and chromes developer tools, but it seems like it should be working to me. Here is my code

```
<div id="new-job">  
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/jobs" class="new_job" id="new_job" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="vfKmC+vnnIl/6icDIbDRfZghNR927qmEqTdB9I2OeMQ="></div>

    <div class="field">
      <label for="job_category">Category</label>
      <select id="job_category" name="job[category]"><option value=""></option>
                <option value="Bistro Card">Bistro Card</option>
                <option value="Dongle">Dongle</option>
                <option value="Return">Return</option>
                <option value="Catering">Catering</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option></select><br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="job_location">Location</label><br>
      <input id="job_location" name="job[location]" size="30" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="job_description">Description</label><br>
      <textarea cols="40" id="job_description" name="job[description]" rows="20"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <input class="button small radius" id="submit-job" name="commit" type="submit" value="create job">
      <a href="/jobs" class="button small radius secondary">go back</a>
      <div id="new-job-errors"> </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And heres my CSS

```
#new-job {
    select {height: 30px;}
}
```

Comment: Before you post your question you should make sure your 'code' is actually correct: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 6):

the correct syntax should be

```
#new-job select {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the `select` element you can use the assigned id, or the tag itself.

An example of both is here - http://jsfiddle.net/9HndG/

In your css, it would look like this:

by id

```
#job_category{
    height:30px;
}
```

by tag

```
select{
    width:200px;
}
```

by both

```
select#job_category{
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: the css style was picked up fine, just like i explained with the other solution. the css is also picked in the matched css style when i look in google chromes development tool. but when i look at the 'computed style' of the development tool it still shows up as 18px

Comment: The computed width most likely excludes the border and padding sizes. If you add border:0; and/or padding:0; does it give the same 18px computed result?

Answer (score 0):

add some style in your `<select>`

```
<select id="job_category" name="job[category]" style="height:30px;">...
```